# Why Arrays are not contravariant?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, covariance

I was wondering :

*As of C# 4.0, generic interfaces permit covariance (as do generic delegates4), but generic classes do not.*

> Arrays support covariance (S[] can be cast to B[] if S subclasses B)

So it is perfectly valid to do this :

```
    string[] obj = new string[3];
        obj[0]="1";
        obj[1]="2";
        obj[2]="3";

Do something with :    (obj as object[])
Do something with :    (object[])obj ...
Do something with :    ((IEnumerable<object>)obj)
```

**But** The downside of this reusability is that element assignments **can fail at runtime**:

```
 (obj as object[])[0] = new DateTime(); //errrr...
```

Ok great - it can fail.

So if it can already fail at runtime (and it's up to me to check it) , why  didn't they make it also as `contravariant` ?

```
      object[] obj = new object[3];
        obj[0]="1";
        obj[1]="2";
        obj[2]="3";
```

So that I will be able to do ( my responsibility) :

```
(obj as string[])...
```

Comment: So you want to be able to write `(string[])(object[])new Button[5]`?

Comment: @SLaks We know that there is a problem here(runtime).I'm just saying that if it's up to me to check the type -- why didnt they make it also contravariant so that i will be able to use it from the other way.

Comment: Isn't this not one of the cases where C# 1.0 just copied what Java did?

Comment: @dtb I have no idea. ( me and java are not friends).

Comment: @dtb: [Yes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx).

Comment: Found it. [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx): "[This particular kind of covariance] was added to the CLR because Java requires it and the CLR designers wanted to be able to support Java-like languages." It doesn't say anything about contravariance, so my guess is that it wasn't added because Java didn't have it and the designers didn't like it anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is bad enough that they allow covariance, because then every time you write to an array, i.e. set one of its elements to a new reference, a type check will have to be performed.

If they allowed contravariance as well, every *read* of the array would need a type check as well. That would be even worse.

In the old days of .NET arrays were often passed where the receiver was expected to only *read* from the array. The "crazy" covariance made a bit sense then. Contravariance was not as useful.